# I want to migrate few Product, Product options etc records from a source org to a Target org while also maintaing their relationships

Tags: apex, rest-api

I already have the access_token for the target org, but I don't know how to proceed further. I can build a REST api to send data to the target org but that won't be sufficient to create a record and also maintain relationships between multiple objects.

It'll be great help for me if someone could reply to this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of building you'd need to do.
Why don't you just use a existing data loader?
[XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler/) will let you do it directly from Excel where you can use lookup formulas to link multiple object tables and upload preserving all the relationships.